# MySQL Variable Error

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (colName nvarchar(500), tableName nvarchar(500))

insert into @myTable

SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME AS colName, c.TABLE_NAME AS tableName, TABLE_SCHEMA tableSchema 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS as c 
WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME like '%password%'

select * from @myTable
```

My error is:

> [Error] Script lines: 1-7 --------------------------
>    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @myTable TABLE (colName nvarchar(500), tableName nvarchar(500))

```
insert ' at line 1
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try to avoid the @ or write \`@myTable\`

Comment: You are using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: You can't declare temporary table using '@' in MySQL it should be `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ..`

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql is a bit different:

```
create table myTable (colName nvarchar(500), tableName nvarchar(500));

insert into myTable (colName, tableName)
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%password%';

select * from myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  insert into myTable  

 SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME AS colName, c.TABLE_NAME AS tableName 
 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS as c 
 WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME like '%password%'
```