# Alternative solutions to table-valued parameters in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, vb.net, table-valued-parameters

Is there anyone who may have found an alternative solution to having table-valued parameters in MYSQL.  My situation is I want to pass in multiple rows from a visual basic front end application and Id like to be able to send in a table of records in one request so i can wrap it in a transaction.  I've done lots of research and still with out answers.  Maybe someone can help me out.

Comment: Try to take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql