# MSSQL to MYSQL conversion

Tags: mysql, sql-server, declare

I have a MSSQL query and would like to convert it to MySQL version. But I have an error in my console:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @selectedTags TABLE (ID int) DECLARE @tagCount int INSER' at line 1
```

My code below:

```
DECLARE @selectedTags TABLE (ID int)
DECLARE @tagCount int

INSERT INTO @selectedTags VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @selectedTags VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @selectedTags VALUES (5)

SELECT @tagCount = COUNT(*) FROM @selectedTags

SELECT
    P.ID
FROM Product P
JOIN ProductTag PT
    ON PT.ProductID = P.ID
JOIN @selectedTags T
    ON T.ID = PT.TagID
GROUP BY
    P.ID,
    P.Name
HAVING COUNT(PT.TagID) = @tagCount
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql

Comment: put ; at the end of lines for the begining

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @selectedTags TABLE (ID int)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

There is no TABLE type in Mysql, you have to CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and INSERT to it.

DECLARE is allowed in stored routines only.
to set @tagCount simply use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @tagCount FROM temp_table;
```