# How to execute SELECT from List SQL query inside the MYSQL function?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a function in MYSQL as follow

```
CREATE FUNCTION `getTaskIds` ( typeIds TEXT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE output TEXT;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) INTO output FROM task WHERE task_id IN (typeIds );
RETURN output;
END
```

when I execute the function like `SELECT getTaskIds( '1,2,3' )`, It gives me the result for only task_id = 1. It does not condider task_id 2 and 3.

What am I missing in the function?
Can you guys help me out?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You might look at alternatives to passing a list of keys as a parameter, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: Sorry mate, I did not get your suggestion.

Comment: At present, you will need to use dynamic sql (e.g. [prepared statemt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5728155/314291) ) to 'append' the list of `task_ids` to be retrieved. Unfortunately, MySql doesn't support Table Valued parameters (SqlServer) or Arrays (Oracle) either, leaving a further alternative of using Temporary tables on the connection. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `IN` since you are passing in a string.  Try this `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) INTO output FROM task WHERE FIND_IN_SET(task_id, typeIds) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all parameters in the function. So if you want 3 parameters:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `getTaskIds` ( typeId1 TEXT, typeId2 TEXT, typeId3 TEXT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE output TEXT;
// do what you want to do
RETURN output;
END
```