# EMBEDDED MYSQL Procedure Declare type

Tags: mysql, procedure, embedded-database

Is it possible to declare parameters with some table struct type in "EMBEDDED MYSQL Procedure" ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Product_p()
BEGIN
    DECLARE ProductValue ProductTable;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create table variable in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Use a [Cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) as parameter
2. Use [Temporary Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-temporary-table), this case you don't have to pass the data, just insert into the `temporary table`, and select in your `procedure`.