# Is there a MySQL equivalent for Oracle's TABLE datatype?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a way to create a variable of type table like the one in oracle.

For Example:

```
TYPE <Typename>  IS TABLE OF <table>.ROW_ID%TYPE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no such datatype available in mysql, but here is a [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql) which can solve your problem.