# Query with CASE statement in Group By I need to create an entry where no results occur in the WHEN

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

I have a query which groups up incoming payments into date ranges (1-7 days, 3-6 months etc.) and it largely works as I had hoped. However, I want to return a row which says 0 when no income is expected in the date range.

The group by looks like this:

```
group by 

CASE    WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 0 and 7 then 1
        WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 8 and 14 then 2
        WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 15 and 30 then 3
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 1 and 2 then 4
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 2 and 3 then 5
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 3 and 6 then 6
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 6 and 12 then 7
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 1 and 2 then 8
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 2 and 3 then 9
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 3 and 4 then 10
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 5 and 6 then 11
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) >= 7 then 12
```

This works correctly in that it will give me the correct amounts, but I want to force the code to give me a 0. So I currently get this:

```
1   300000
5   150000
8   300000
```

What I actually want is this:

```
1   300000
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   150000
6   0
7   0
8   300000
etc.
```

This is the entire query - I've tried using an IFNULL() but had no success:

```
select

sum(data.principaldue+data.interestdue) as m

from
(select
    la.id
    ,rep.duedate
    ,rep.PRINCIPALDUE
    ,rep.INTERESTDUE
    from repayment rep
    join loanaccount la on la.ENCODEDKEY = rep.PARENTACCOUNTKEY
    join loanproduct lp on lp.ENCODEDKEY = la.PRODUCTTYPEKEY

group by 

CASE    WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 0 and 7 then 1
        WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 8 and 14 then 2
        WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 15 and 30 then 3
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 1 and 2 then 4
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 2 and 3 then 5
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 3 and 6 then 6
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 6 and 12 then 7
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 1 and 2 then 8
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 2 and 3 then 9
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 3 and 4 then 10
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 5 and 6 then 11
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) >= 7 then 12

 END 

Order by

CASE    WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 0 and 7 then 1
        WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 8 and 14 then 2
        WHEN timestampdiff(day,curdate(),data.duedate) between 15 and 30 then 3
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 1 and 2 then 4
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 2 and 3 then 5
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 3 and 6 then 6
        WHEN timestampdiff(month,curdate(),data.duedate) between 6 and 12 then 7
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 1 and 2 then 8
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 2 and 3 then 9
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 3 and 4 then 10
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) between 5 and 6 then 11
        WHEN timestampdiff(year,curdate(),data.duedate) >= 7 then 12

 END
```

Comment: You could right join it with a numbers table?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have a numbers table in this schema, and I don't have authorization to create tables either.

Comment: Use a table variable for this.

Comment: Sorry - I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, just found mysql doesn't have table variables (declared tables). You would have to use a temp table for this.

Comment: Thanks - since your last comment I had tried a temporary table, but my login doesn't have that authorization either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but would be too big for comments;

A temporary table with numbers could be useful:

[MySql temporary tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (num int); 
INSERT INTO TmpTable VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 ...);
```

Then you could right join on this table to make sure missing values are included.

Lets say you have this:

```
results(num, val):
1   300000
5   150000
8   300000
```

This should result in your desired output:

```
SELECT numbers.num, COALESCE(results.val, 0) as val
FROM results RIGHT JOIN TempTable numbers on results.num = numbers.num
WHERE numbers.num <= 12 --or other max number

1   300000
2   0
...
5   150000
...
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

If you don't have permission to create temporary tables, look for a workaround to select consecutive integers, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql):

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, t.*
FROM some_table t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

Where `some_table` is any table with enough rows.

Probably use a top N on that.

Another dirty workaround, might be good enough if you don't need many numbers:

```
SELECT 1 num
UNION
SELECT 2 num
UNION
...
```

**Edit:**

Slightly tidier workaround:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), ... ) x(i)
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer, but i'm afraid I don't have the relevant privileges to create temporary tables in the schema.

Comment: I only saw your comment after having posted this. Will update the answer if can think of anything else.

Comment: Hi - i only need to go up to 14 in the numbers table, so i think that although a little obtuse i'll use the UNION option. Regardless, it works! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, did you use `TEMPORARY` keyword for your table? These are allocated per connection, and I would have thought to not require special permissions.

Comment: I did use temporary, but apparently even these require special privileges.