# MySQL Stored Procedure Data Container

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Does MySQL have **variable table** as SQL-Server or **user-defined-type** in Oracle? My scenario is to select records into a container and iterate through the container for further action.

I had tried **CURSOR** but seems not efficient when comes to multiple columns. Also tried **CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE** with **IS EXIST**, due to the life cycle, I believe is not a good practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create table variable in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: What are you using here? `mysql` and `sql-server` are 2 completely different RDBMS, and `plsql` isn't used by either of them (it's used by `oracle`). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50696511/edit) your post and correct your tags. Thanks.

Comment: Temporary tables live and die with your connection.

Comment: Hi Mohammad Chavoshi, definitely not duplicated. I had tried tmp table. 

Hi Larnu, please understand that i am going to use MySQL, looking for something similar as variable table or user-defined-type. 

Hi krish KM, correct, that why I am said above, it is not a good practice for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have **table variable**. Use **cursor** to iterate selected dataset will be the practice so far. Bear in mind, **cursor** should exist **once** in a **begin end** block, consecutive needs should use nested **begin end** block to wrap up your cursor.

Answer (score -1):

sometimes cursor is costly. In oracle, you can create user defined object and can be use it as a list.
like this:-

```
create or replace type lv_your_object as object(
    cloumn1 INTEGER,
    column2 VARCHAR2(1000),
    column3 VARCHAR2(1000),
    cloumn4 INTEGER,
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE lv_your_object_list FORCE IS TABLE OF lv_your_object;
/
```

Comment: The question is about user-defined-type replacement in MySQL.

Comment: Hi Atul Dey, thanks for reply, I am looking for MySQL approach.

Comment: oh,, np - i saw you mentioned "in oracle".