# Get multiple rows result from a mysql variable

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am having a query, which I kept inside a variable, Its working fine when only one result is available, for more than one results, its showing below error

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Can anyone tell me, how to get multiple result set in a MySQL variable

My query is

```
SET @v1 = (SELECT id FROM `employee` where DATE_ADD(last_active_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(last_active_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)=CURRENT_DATE AND employee_group!=3);

SELECT @v1;
```

Comment: You can't , unless you group_Concat which may make @v1 useless..A temporary table may be appropriate

Comment: Or a cursor in a stored procedure. Or return the results in json and use json_table() to turn the results into a proper table in the second select.

Comment: There is table valued variable in MSSQL so it is possible, but not on MySQL, instead you may use temporary table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql/1524918

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,  I will try